# Render Primefaces component in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean

JSF 2.2 + Primefaces 5.0 + Managed Bean

I just want to do a simple thing:

I want to render a primefaces component in JSF site using a managed bean.

JSF:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>BeanTest</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        #{testBean.output}

    </h:body>
</html>
```

The managed bean:

```
public class TestBean {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of TestBean
     */
    public TestBean() {
    }

        private String output = "<p:calendar mode=\"inline\"/>";

    /**
     * Get the value of output
     *
     * @return the value of output
     */
    public String getOutput() {            
        return output;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of output
     *
     * @param output new value of output
     */
    public void setOutput(String output) {
        this.output = output;
    }
}
```

The result is the text **`<p:calendar mode=\"inline\"/>`**.

How can I get the primefaces component rendered?

If I use it the regular way (the bean only sets attributes of primefaces components), everything works fine.

Comment: What's your real purpose here?

Comment: It is possible to add component from your managed bean.

Comment: Why would you do it this way? You can create components in your backing bean and then make a binding to the component in the component tree, if you want to manipulate if from the bean. 

If you want to conditionally render a component, then you should use the rendered attribute.

Thats why kolossus is asking what are you trying to achieve, then perhaps we will be able to help you?

What you are doing right now is just wrong.

Comment: You can't do it this way. Primefaces component need to be converted to HTML by the JSF servlet before presenting to the user. What you're doing circumvents this process. Additionally, JSF will escape special characters to avoid injection attacks. You can, however, render html this way by using an <h:outputText escape="false"